# Create a variable in VB.Net based on Architecture

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, variables, architecture

I am very new to VB i have been using Batch mostly i have now created half an app in vb.net to test what i can do.
I have looked around before posting this question but not found anything specific to what i am looking for.

The tool is for LAN networks so I need to be able to input and pc name or ip address into a textbox then click a button and launch sccm via that button but make it connect to the ip/pc name in the box.

So in batch i have this:

```
    :GET OS ARCHITECTURE
REG QUERY "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT
IF %OS%==32BIT SET X=x86
IF %OS%==64BIT SET X=x64

::Acquire the Computer Name or IP Address for the Workstation
    set /p WS="Enter the Computer Name (PCNUMBER) if this fails get IP Address for the Workstation:"

    :SCCM
    ECHO SCCM is now running
    IF %OS%==32BIT START PSTOOLS\psexec.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe" %WS%
    IF %OS%==64BIT START PSTOOLS\psexec.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\Bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe" %WS%
```

How would i do the same but in VB.Net without using Process.Start and referring to a batch file. i want the app to run as a stand alone exe

I have this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim WS As String
        Dim IP As String

        WS = txtWS.Text
        IP = txtIP.Text

        Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\Bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe", "/WS")
    End Sub
```

But it does not pull the text from WS and i am unsure as to how to make the program know whether to run from program files x86 or program files.

Comment: and how would you like your coffee? This is not a free coding site. Please show us your efforts, where are you stuck, place a specific question,and you will receive help from other users.

Comment: I just forgot to add the code i had sorry! i have updated the first post

Comment: not sure what arguments you try to pass, only `/WS` the content of `WS` variable, both `/WS ws_content`? As a rule of thumb I would use `Dim args = String.Format("/WS {0}", txtWS.Text);` or 
`Dim args = String.Format("/WS {0} {1}", txtWS.Text, txtIP.Text);` or (if need quotes) `Dim args = String.Format("/WS {0}{1}{0} {0}{2}{0}", """", txtWS.Text, txtIP.Text);` and then `Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\...\CmRcViewer.exe", args)`

Comment: Thanks! its not exactly an argument its a variable you can open cmrcviewer.exe ith any hostname ip so i wanted to pull this from a text box and make it open i accomplished it by:

 Dim WS As String
        Dim IP As String
        Dim args = String.Format("/WS {0}", txtWS.Text)

        WS = txtWS.Text
        IP = txtIP.Text

        Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\Bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe", txtWS.Text)

Answer (score 0):

The code below has worked

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim WS As String
    Dim IP As String

    WS = txtWS.Text
    IP = txtIP.Text

    If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\Bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe", txtWS.Text)
    Else
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\Bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe", txtWS.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: think, your line should be `Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\...\CmRcViewer.exe", args)` instead of `Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\...\CmRcViewer.exe", txtWS.Text)`

Comment: yeah your right but it should work with Dim args = String.Format("/WS {0}", txtWS.Text) taken out completely, no need for args at all. now i just need to make it detect whether x86 or x64

Comment: then see `Environment.Is64Bit...`

Comment: Thanks Alot! it  but i think its:
Environment.Is 64BitOperatingSystem

Comment: or `Is64BitProcess` you may be running a 32 bit process in a 64 bit machine. you know what you try to accomplish, but take it into account... ;)

Comment: well if you use x 64 the program i am trying to run will be located in program files x86 and if on 64 just [rogram files so i just want to run the correct file with correct path, so i think in this instance its the OperatingSystem that should be checked ?